# send multipart/form-data using httpsendrequest

Tags: c++, c, wininet

I'm trying to send multipart/form-data using httpsendrequest in c++ but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using the RFC standard for boundary and this is the code I have. I'm sending simple data, plain but trying to use multipart/form-data so I can understand how boundaries work but it doesn't send. This is the code that I've got so far.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x600

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024

static LPCTSTR acceptTypes[] = {"*/*", NULL};
static const char *postData = "submit=submit&cool=hawk";
static char headers[] = TEXT("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=abcde\r\n"
                            "--abcde\r\n"
                            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cool\"\r\n"
                            "testval\r\n"
                            "--abcde\r\n");

int main()
{
    HINTERNET hSession, hConnect, hFile;

    if( ( hSession = InternetOpen(
        "myapp",
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0
    ) ) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Couldn't start session. Error %ld\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Session started\n");

    if( ( hConnect = InternetConnect(
        hSession,
        "localhost",
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
        0,
        0
    ) ) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server. Error %ld\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected to server\n");

    if( ( hFile = HttpOpenRequest(
        hConnect,
        "POST",
        "/test/index.php",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        acceptTypes,
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,
        0
    ) ) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Unable to open request. Error %ld\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Opening request..Opened\n");

    unsigned long dataLen = strlen(postData)+1;
    bool res = HttpSendRequest(
        hFile,
        headers,
        -1,
        (char*)postData,
        dataLen
    );
    if( !res )
    {
        printf("Unable to send request. Error %ld\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Request sent\n");

//  char *szBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFLEN);
    char szBuffer[BUFLEN];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;

    memset(&szBuffer, '\0', sizeof(szBuffer));

    while( InternetReadFile(hFile, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRead) && dwRead )
    {
        printf("%s", szBuffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset(szBuffer, '\0', sizeof(szBuffer));` without the ampersand suffices.

Comment: agreed but the data is still not sent